# Certain API's in flutter require ui.Image. In some cases (certainly for prototyping), I'd use built-in Icons.xyz. How to convert to image?

Tags: flutter, dart, graphics

Certain API's in Flutter require you pass a ui.Image.  In some cases (certainly for prototyping), I'd use built-in Icons.xyz.  How can I convert Icon or IconData to a ui.Image?

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? Like certain cases